# Is it possible to call socketio.emit from a job scheduled via ApScheduler (BackgroundScheduler)?

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

Here is what I am trying to do
I have a Flask app that is responding to clients requests
The same is also running some jobs to collect information from various sources
This is done by using ApScheduler and BackgroundScheduler
I would like that at the end of the job to send the webclient an update with the results of the job

Below is the code  but it is not really working.

**Here is the server side**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def get_updates(socketio):
    socketio.emit('updates', {'updates': "this is the updates"})
return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not app.debug or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':  #prevents scheduling the job twice -When in debug mode this runs twice
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(func=get_updates, trigger="interval", seconds=30, kwargs={"socketio":socketio})
        scheduler.start()
    socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=5001)
```

**Browser side**

```
<html>
<div>
   
  <ul id="messages" style="list-style-type:none;" ></ul>
    <form id="chat" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>


<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
      socket.send('Hello world');
    });
    var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    var form = document.getElementById('chat');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
  
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (input.value) {
        socket.emit('message', input.value);
        input.value = '';
      }
    });
  
  
    socket.on('updates', function(msg) {
      console.log("Updates received")
      console.log(msg)
      var item = document.createElement('li');
      item.textContent = msg;
      messages.appendChild(item);
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

**Update:** While reading as much as I can about his I was watching the console and I noticed that this worked once in like 50 exectutions of the scheduled job

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is wasting a day of reading to solve this here is the solution
Add these lines before any imports related to flask or apscheduler

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(thread=True, time=True)
```

See [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1457)  and [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1456) and also the [docs for eventlet regarding the monkey patching](https://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20important,monkey_patch%20multiple%20times.)